# C++ : no matching function

Tags: c++, bind, functor

I am trying to replicate a problem I have, but now code fails earlier.

Code so far is :

```
namespace
{
    // this cannot change either - needs to be static
   static bool imp( const int  a , const int b )
   {
      return a != b ;
   }
}

template < typename KEY , 
           typename VALUE, 
           typename CALLBACK = VALUE(*)( const KEY & ) > class ComplexObject
{
     public :
     ComplexObject( CALLBACK ){} ;
     ///......
     // cannot change that so cannot provide default constructor!!!
     //.... more functions that utilite KEY.VALUE - imagine this is a cache
};

using namespace std::placeholders;  // for _1, _2, _3...

typedef std::function<bool(*)( const int)> myFunctor ; 

class TypeA
{
public:
    TypeA(const int id) : n_id(id) ,  n_co( std::bind( &imp , n_id , _1 ) ) {}
    bool check( const int a, const int id ) ;
private :
    int n_id;
    ComplexObject < int, bool, myFunctor > n_co ;
protected :
     TypeA() : n_id(0) , n_co( std::bind( &imp , n_id , _1 )) { }
};
```

Or [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7aa64dc9f957ab37).

Error is :

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp: In constructor 'TypeA::TypeA(int)':
main.cpp:32:75: error: no matching function for call to 'ComplexObject<int, bool, std::function<bool (*)(int)> >::ComplexObject(std::_Bind_helper<false, bool (*)(int, int), int&, const std::_Placeholder<1>&>::type)'
     TypeA(const int id) : n_id(id) ,  n_co( std::bind( &imp , n_id , _1 ) ) {}
```

Comment: Rather use `std::function`.

Comment: can you give an example? I need to use std::bind because of the rest of my implementation.

Comment: I don't get why you should need that. You should use the appropriate `std::function` with the require parameter types as constructor parameter, rather than a template parameter.

Comment: `std::function<bool(*)(const int)>` should be `std::function<bool(const int)>`, with a `public:` `ComplexObject( CALLBACK )`.

Comment: that works but the default implementation of CALLBACK isn't that, so I assume that there must be a reason for that. FYI I cannot change my ComplexObject.

Comment: @ghostrider The default implementation is a function pointer rather than a `std::function`, so the `*` is necessary there. But the `*` must be omitted from the `std::function`

Comment: hmm I see - ok need probably to read about function pointers. I will try that with the rest of my program because I have more failures now and get back if I need more help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::function<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) template argument is *function type*, rather that *pointer to function type*.

The following change fixes it:

```
typedef std::function<bool(int)> myFunctor;
```

Only in C++17 you can use [`std::function<bool(*)(int)>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/deduction_guides).

Comment: indeed but then, rest of the code ( that is not visible here ) fails. And reason is that CALLBACK inside my ComplexObject expects a VALUE(*)( const KEY & ) -- hence the bool(*) .

Comment: can you explain why this change in typedef fixes it, because I don't get it :)

Comment: @ghostrider Updated the answer for you.